# Optimise android apps for phones with the new ratio's like the S8 (18.5:9)?

Tags: android, react-native

Just got the new S8 and I'm trying to update my android (react-native) apps because there is a black bar on top of the screen because of the app scaling of the ratio 37:18 / 18.5:9. Adding fixed height and width to the app doesn't work I still get that black bar in top. Removing the statusbar seems like removing a bit on top and at the bottom.

As an example I created a new react-native app but a native Android has the same problems.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! Jeej.

Found out via a [post of Nato Marin](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) you can just add `<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />` in the `<application>` element in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Result: Black bar gone :)

[image]

Comment: Hi,I am android developer and I got problem on Samsung s8 and s8+ with image my image display nice in all other device but in s8 and s8 image cut from left and right why this happened i don't know. Please help me ?

Comment: With the new feature to hide the virtual home and back buttons on the s8 i notice the window dimensions dont update to full reolution causing problems with the layout